# How to clean Maven cache from Grails command/SDK?

Tags: maven, grails, ivy, dependency-management

I'm looking for a Grails SDK command (i.e. something like `grails maven-clean`) that will clean my local `.m2\` cache, forcing the rest of the Grails build (`grails war`, `grails run-app`, etc.) to re-fetch them from the remote repos. Ideas?

Comment: It actually doesn't need to be a pure Grails SDK command; just something that would be available to a shell if Grails/Groovy is already installed on the system.

Comment: Why would you want to refetch the dependencies if they haven't changed?

Comment: Thanks @chad (+1) - Maybe some of these deps are SNAPSHOT versions (currently under active development) of other in-house libs. Hence if my app depends on `somelib-SNAPSHOT.jar`, the SNAPSHOT might change every few hours as other in-house devs publish new versions of it.

Comment: If you have snapshots just specify the changing policy. See

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#changingDependencies

Note it differs depending if you Aether or Ivy. Aether is recommended though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have u tried ..> `refresh dependencies` and then issue `grails clean` on command line ...some time `deleting the bogus file` under `./m2` and `refresh dependencies` might save a lot of time...

also : related to `grails maven-clean -U` command check this one

`grails maven help`

```
mavenRepo ("http://my.server/repos/my-grails-plugins") {
    updatePolicy 'always'
}
```

Here are the possible values for updatePolicy:

```
never – Never check for new snapshots
always – Always check for new snapshots
daily – Check once a day for new snapshots (the default)
interval:x – Check once every x minutes for new snapshots
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AndreschSerj thankyou! see who is running the show now?

Answer (score 1):

Maven will check for new versions of dependencies if you use the -U flag on the mvn command line for your build.  I believe it only checks for new versions of SNAPSHOT dependencies once every 24 hrs if you don't use the -U.

Comment: Thanks @chad (+1) - though you say "*Normally...*" - can this behaviour (24 hrs) be configured or modified? If so, any clue as to how? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think it can be.  I'll edit out that normally, it's misleading.  I think what I meant to suggest is that it ALSO does some other stuff, like clear the cache of things like "I couldn't find that one" . . . i.e. it won't try to find a missing artifact again for 24 hours.

Comment: BTW, you should accept the answer if it works for you.  It's a key part of making this site a useful repository of info.